# Is there a way to get only the text changed when text is changed in a textfield in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have a textfield in flutter and I was wondering if there was a way to get only the changed text, we can call it delta, when the text in the textfield changes.

```
TextField(
    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
    controller: _controller,
    focusNode: _focusNode,
    cursorColor: Colors.red,
    onChanged: (s) {
      print(s);
    },
),
```

With the following code I'll only get the whole text value when the text changes.

For example: if the text in the textfield is "*Hello worl*" and I add a "*d*" the value in the onChanged is "Hello world".
Is there a way to get only the text that was inserted/deleted/cut/pasted with the location the action was performed?

I would like to get a variable of a custom type, let's say CustomTextAction which contains a index, for where the text was changed, an action type, for what type of action was performed and a value for what was changed or something similar. For example in the case above it would be:

```
CustomTextAction:
- index: 10
- type: "insertion"
- value: "d"
```

Does a feature like this already exist in Flutter or should I code it by myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the logic.

```
class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  getNewValue(String oldValue, String currentValue) {
    if (oldValue.length < currentValue.length) {
      String newLetter = currentValue.replaceAll(oldValue, "")[0];
      print("You added: " + newLetter);
      return newLetter;
    } else {
      String newLetter = oldValue.replaceAll(currentValue, "")[0];
      print("You deleted: " + newLetter);
      return newLetter;
    }
  }

  String oldValue = "";
//   TextEditingController _controller = new TextEditingController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          TextFormField(onChanged: (currentValue) {
            String newValue = getNewValue(oldValue, currentValue);
            oldValue = currentValue;
            print(newValue);
          }),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

It gives just last letter you added but you can use the function in the onEditingComplete to get full changes.